# how to replace an element in a tuple with something else?

Tags: python, nlp

hi i'm new to programming and i need to do some text processing with python, what i need to do is to replace an element in a tuple. i already have a list of tuples that looks like this

```
my_list=[('the','b'),('apple','i'),('is','o'),('delicious','o')]
```

and i would like to change the second element in the tuple, if the second is 'b' or 'i', i would like to change it into 'yes', if the second element in the tuple is 'o', then do nothing.

i would love to know if there's some nice and clean way to do that in python.
thank you so much.

Comment: I'm confused. If the second element is "o", should it change to "yes", or should it do nothing?

Comment: You can access the contents of a tuple in a list by using a two-dimensional index: mylist[1][1] == 'i' # is true. Once you can access each element, you can compare it.

Answer (score 0):

> if the second is 'o' or 'i', i would like to change it into 'yes'
>   if the second element in the tuple is 'o', then do nothing.

You mentioned "o" twice here so I assume one of them is a typo for "b". I assume that if the second element is "o", then do nothing, otherwise the second element should become "yes".

```
>>> my_list=[('the','b'),('apple','i'),('is','o'),('delicious','o')]
>>> my_list = [(first, "yes" if second == "b" or second == "i" else second) for first, second in my_list]
>>> my_list
[('the', 'yes'), ('apple', 'yes'), ('is', 'o'), ('delicious', 'o')]
```

Comment: oh i'm sorry. i meant that if the second is 'b' or 'i' then change it to 'yes', otherwise do nothing